# Compiling a C++ program with Chilkat library

Tags: 14.04, compiling, c++, g++

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRwIW.png) is the error I get when compiling my program with the Chilkat library. I understand that I need to include the "-l" but when I include that, it gives me this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lchilkat-9.5.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I downloaded the Chilkat C/C++ Library from [here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatLinux.asp). I don't really know how to use the .a or .so to compile my .cpp file.

[This](https://codeshare.io/5gppV8) is my source code. The libraries are stored in the directory i included.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "chilkat/include/CkFtp2.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    CkFtp2 ftp;

    bool success;

    //  Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
    success = ftp.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial");
    if (success != true) {
        std::cout << ftp.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
        return 0;
    }

    ftp.put_Hostname("ftp.someFtpServer.com");
    ftp.put_Username("****");
    ftp.put_Password("****");

    //  Connect and login to the FTP server.
    success = ftp.Connect();
    if (success != true) {
        std::cout << ftp.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //  Change to the remote directory where the file will be uploaded.
    success = ftp.ChangeRemoteDir("junk");
    if (success != true) {
        std::cout << ftp.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //  Upload a file.
    const char *localFilename = "c:/temp/hamlet.xml";
    const char *remoteFilename = "hamlet.xml";

    success = ftp.PutFile(localFilename,remoteFilename);
    if (success != true) {
        std::cout << ftp.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
        return 0;
    }

    success = ftp.Disconnect();

    std::cout << "File Uploaded!" << "\r\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to compile your program with the following:

```
    g++ test.cpp -Lchilkat/lib -lchilkat-9.5.0 -o test
```

-L gives the path where the library is stored

-l gives the name of the library